# Using Identity Insert on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, import, linked-server, identity, azure-vm

We have a database hosted in Microsoft Azure and using this database connection details I have created a linked server object in SSMS on our on-premise SQL box and I can insert into it as following syntax:

```
insert into [Azure].[budget].dbo.Bill
```

I wanted to set identity insert on and have tried the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Azure].[budget].dbo.Bill ON
insert into [Azure].[budget].dbo.Bill
```

I was then informed that I would have to use dynamic SQL for this so I changed to the following:

```
EXEC [Azure].[budgetenergy].dbo.sp_executesql N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bill ON;insert into Bill ([FIELD LIST]) select [FIELD LIST] from [DUOS3NF].dbo.bill where dateOfIssue > ''10 mar 2015''';
```

The [DUOS3NF] is a database that is on the SMSS box it is not a linked server. Using this approach is there any way that I can insert into the linked server the results of the select statement of another database?

When I execute the query the error it does not recognise the database.

Answer (score 1):

Linked servers aren't usually a good idea from a security perspective. See distribution statistics section [here](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/linked-servers-and-distributed-queries/)

I think SSIS would provide a better way of doing this.

Comment: Is there a means of trying to accomplish what I need and have my own database be recognised in the select statement?

Comment: EXEC [Azure].[budget].dbo.sp_executesql N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bill ON;insert into Bill (BillId,MPRN,CustomerName)
select billId,MPRN,customerName
from [DUOS3NF].dbo.bill;SET IDENTITY_INSERT Bill OFF'

Comment: I am trying the above on my SMSS box where the [DUOS3NF] database is hosted but I am getting reference to database not supported on this version of sql